# How to solve database is not mounted

Tags: oracle-10g

```
SQL>    
SQL> alter database mount;    
alter database mount    
*    
ERROR at line 1:    
ORA-00204: error in reading (block 3, # blocks 8) of control file    
ORA-00202: control file:    
'E:\APP\SHAVULHAMEED\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL'    
ORA-27070: async read/write failed    
OSD-04006: ReadFile() failure, unable to read from file    
O/S-Error: (OS 1117) The request could not be performed because of an I/O    
device error.
```

Comment: Is the file on a network share?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple control files then you can try to copy another one over this corrupted one. Otherwise you need to restore it from an (RMAN) backup.